# Two problems on analytic function and Mapping of elementary functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a region and let $f$ and $g$ be analytic functions on $G$ such that $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z \in G$. Show that either $f$ or $g$ is identically zero on $G$.

Here is how I do it: Assume $f$ is non zero on $B(a,R)$, then $fg=0$ implies $a$ is a root of $g$ (of order $n>0$). Therefore $g(z)=(z-a)^nF(z)$ for some non zero analytic function $F(z)$. And then I can't move any more...

The second question is to determine the image of $\{z=x+iy : -\pi < x < \pi,
y=3\}$ under the mapping $u+iv = w = \sin z$.

Comment: Zeroes of analytic function cannot have an accumulation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a consequence of the identity theorem: Assume $f \not= 0$, then $$N := \{z \in G; f(z) = 0 \}$$ has no accumulation point (otherwise, the identity theorem would imply $f=0$ since $G$ is a region). Clearly, $g|_{G \setminus N} = 0$ since $f \cdot g=0$. Since $G \setminus N$ has an accumulation point, the identity theorem states $g=0$.
2. By definition, $$\sin z = \frac{1}{2\imath} (e^{\imath \, z} - e^{-\imath \, z})$$ Now set $z=x+3\imath$, $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$, to calculate the image of the given set.

Comment: thank you! But I wanna ask why $G\N$ has an accumulation point?

Comment: @Excelsior $G$ is open and $N$ has no accumulation point in $G$. This implies that $G \setminus N$ has an accumulation point in $G$. (Choose $x \in G,r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq G$, then $B(x,\delta) \subseteq G \setminus N$ for $\delta<r$ sufficiently small.)